# wxPython: Items in BoxSizer don't expand horizontally, only vertically

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have several buttons in various sizers and they expand in the way that I want them to. However, when I add the parent to a new wx.BoxSizer that is used to add a border around all the elements in the frame, the sizer that has been added functions correctly vertically, but not horizontally.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import wx
import webbrowser

class App(wx.App):


    def OnInit(self):
       frame = MainFrame()
       frame.Show()
       self.SetTopWindow(frame)
       return True


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    title = 'Title'


    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, self.title)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        #icon = wx.Icon('icon.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        #self.SetIcon(icon)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1, vgap=10, hgap=10)

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'BUTTON')
        sizer.Add(button1, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        buttonSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=4, vgap=10, hgap=5)

        buttonDelete = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Delete')
        buttonSizer.Add(buttonDelete, 0, 0)

        buttonEdit = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'Edit')
        buttonSizer.Add(buttonEdit, 0, 0)

        buttonNew = wx.Button(panel, -1, 'New')
        buttonSizer.Add(buttonNew, 0, 0)

        buttonSizer.AddGrowableCol(0, 0)

        sizer.Add(buttonSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.HORIZONTAL)

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(0, 0)
        sizer.AddGrowableRow(0, 0)

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.EXPAND)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

        #panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        #sizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(mainSizer)
        mainSizer.SetSizeHints(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Commenting out lines **57** and **58** and uncommenting lines **55** and **56** removes the extra BoxSizer and shows how I expect everything to function (without the whitespace of course).

I am completely stuck with this problem and still have no clue as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, you're passing some flags incorrectly.  BoxSizer takes wxHORIZONTAL or wxVERTICAL, not wxEXPAND.  sizer.Add does not take wxHORIZONTAL.

If you have a VERTICAL BoxSizer, wxEXPAND will make the control fill horizontally, while a proportion of 1 or more (second argument to Add) will make the control fill vertically.  It's the opposite for HORIZONTAL BoxSizers.

```
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wxVERTICAL)
sizer.Add(widget1, 0, wxEXPAND)
sizer.Add(widget2, 1)
```

widget1 will expand horizontally.  widget2 will expand vertically.

If you put a sizer in another sizer, you need to be sure to have its proportion and EXPAND flags set so that its insides will grow how you want them to.

I'll leave the rest to you.